# Aura doesn't print <> combination of signs

Tags: apex, character-encoding

Does anyone know why Aura doesn't show this combination of signs:

```
<>
```

Namely, if I try to print the message with those combination of signs in it the message skip either part of text between those signs or that two signs. For example, I tried to show this message:

```
<>test<>test<>test<>
```

The output will be:

```
test
```

This is how I try to print message

```
<lightning:formattedRichText value="{!message.value__c}" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you trying to display this? In a log via `system.debug()`? On a visualforce page or lightning component? Please [edit] your question to add clarification.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question, the problem is in Aura component.

Comment: How are you trying to display the message, though? Please make sure to include your code.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @sfdcfox, I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour in the sense that it sanitizes the output (based on the "Supported HTML Tags and attributes" at the [help page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-rich-text/documentation)):

> The component sanitizes HTML tags passed to the value attribute to prevent XSS vulnerabilities. It also ensures that the formatted output is valid HTML. For example, if you have mismatched tags like My Title, the component returns My Title.

The help page also explains that you can escape the tags if you want to display them:

> To pass in HTML tags in your component markup, escape the tags like this.

```
<template>
    <lightning-formatted-rich-text value="&lt;h1>TEST&lt;/h1>">
    </lightning-formatted-rich-text>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your case is for hardcoded values, but my values are dynamic (custom fields)...

Comment: The idea is the same, the only difference is that records may come from `@wire`.